# Spring AuthenticationFailureHandler and WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter loginPage()

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

**Edit: Solved. See my comment after this post**

I am currently implementing a Webapplication with Spring-Security. I have implemented a custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler` which checks if a user tried to login with wrong credentials too often (and blocks him for serveral minutes). But normal failed logins should redirect the user to the login page with the parameter error (`/login?error`). This page shows an error message like "The password you typed in was wrong"

The `AutenticationFailureHandler` looks like this (without the uninteressting linse of code)

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
// Some variables 

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

// some logic here..

request.setAttribute("param", "error");
response.sendRedirect("/login?error");

}
```

My WebApplicationSecurity class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
CustomAuthenticationHandler customAuthenticationHandler;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .failureHandler(customAuthenticationHandler)
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll();

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/css/**", "/img/**", "/js/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated();

    http
        .csrf()
        .disable();
}

@Bean
CustomAuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler() {
    return new CustomAuthenticationHandler();
}

@Configuration
protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
        GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("*******")
            .password("*******")
            .roles("USER");
    }
}
}
```

The problem now is that the `AuthenticationFailureHandler` redirects to `/login?error` but (i don't know why) another redirect is done to `/login`.

Can you help me to solve my problem?

Comment: Do you by any chance invoke super.onAuthenticationFailure at any point? Could Spring be automatically doing it for some reason?

Comment: Well, i solved it by adding "/login**" to `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/img/**", "/js/**")`

Comment: Oh, so login itself (with params) wasn't acessible... The oldest mistake in the book :/

Comment: Yes. Maybe i should consider not to code at new years day ;)

Comment: @smsnheck Add your first comment as the answer! I found solution because of it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, i solved it by adding "/login**" to `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/img/**", "/js/**")`