# Unable to set a custom authentication failure handler in 4.0 spring security

Tags: spring-security

I want to set up custom AuthenticationFailureHandler in my project. Even though I configure my authenticationFailureHandler as below , it is not properly picked up when the sign-in fails.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

..................
@Inject
private AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler;
..................

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/signin").failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/signin")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/search").and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/signout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/signin")
                .permitAll().and().csrf();
    }
```

My custom AuthenticationFailureHandler Class

```
@Component
public class AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Custom code
    }
}
```

When I debug the application, the method `onAuthenticationFailure` is called from `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`, but not in my custom `AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler` even though I extend the same `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`.

What could be the mistake or any missed configuration to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

In this case, when we set the custom `AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler` and then we configure `failureUrl("/signin")`,the configuration `failureUrl("/signin")` will overwrite the already configured `AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler` with a new `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`.

This is the implementation of `failureUrl` and `failureHandler` methods as in `AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer`.

```
   public abstract class AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer<B extends HttpSecurityBuilder<B>, T extends AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer<B, T, F>, F extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter> extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<T, B> {

    ...........
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;
    private String failureUrl;
    ..........

    public final T failureUrl(String authenticationFailureUrl) {
        T result = failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureUrl));
        this.failureUrl = authenticationFailureUrl;
        return result;
    }

    public final T failureHandler(AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler) {
        this.failureUrl = null;
        this.failureHandler = authenticationFailureHandler;
        return getSelf();
    }

}
```

If we set only the `failurehandler` as below, our custom AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler will be set.

```
        .formLogin().loginPage("/signin")
           .permitAll()
           .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
           .defaultSuccessUrl("/search").and()
```

If we want to set the failure URL we can set it in the custom `AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler` using `setDefaultFailureUrl(String defaultFailureUrl)` which is derived from it's parent class `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor in your `AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler` class and pass in the `defaultFailureUrl` parameter down to the parent clss you extend (`SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`).  Your `AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler` class would look like: -

```
@Component
public class AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    public AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler (String defaultFailureUrl) {
        super(defaultFailureUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Custom code
    }
}
```

Your configure block would then look like this: -

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/signin")
                .failureHandler(new AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler("/signin?auth=failure") // or whatever is a sensible url
                .permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/search").and()

               ...
```

Note, it's really important that the `"/signin?auth=failure"` is added to an `authorizeRequests()` section otherwise the controller won't pick up the `auth` parameter e.g.

```
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                "/css/**", 
                "/js/**", 
                "/images/**", 
                "/signin**"          // REALLY IMPORTANT !!!
            ).permitAll()
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39618113/1692179 for more information on that.

Your controller can now check for the `auth` parameter e.g.

```
@Controller
public class SigninController 

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handleError (Model model, 
                               @RequestParam(name = "auth", required = false) String auth) {
        if ("error".equals(auth)) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "invalid username/password");
        }

        return "login";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! :-)